# Convert Object type to Float type

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

This goal is to convert the type from 'object' to 'float' from KDD 99 dataset.

This is the information of the dataset :

```
class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'
RangeIndex: 494020 entries, 0 to 494019
Data columns (total 42 columns):
duration                       494020 non-null int64
protocol_type                  494020 non-null object
service                        494020 non-null object
src_bytes                      494020 non-null object
dst_bytes                      494020 non-null int64
flag                           494020 non-null int64
land                           494020 non-null int64
wrong_fragment                 494020 non-null int64
urgent                         494020 non-null int64
hot                            494020 non-null int64
num_failed_logins              494020 non-null int64
logged_in                      494020 non-null int64
num_compromised                494020 non-null int64
root_shell                     494020 non-null int64
su_attempted                   494020 non-null int64
num_root                       494020 non-null int64
num_file_creations             494020 non-null int64
num_shells                     494020 non-null int64
num_access_files               494020 non-null int64
num_outbound_cmds              494020 non-null int64
is_hot_login                   494020 non-null int64
is_guest_login                 494020 non-null int64
count                          494020 non-null int64
serror_rate                    494020 non-null int64
rerror_rate                    494020 non-null float64
same_srv_rate                  494020 non-null float64
diff_srv_rate                  494020 non-null float64
srv_count                      494020 non-null float64
srv_serror_rate                494020 non-null float64
srv_rerror_rate                494020 non-null float64
srv_diff_host_rate             494020 non-null float64
dst_host_count                 494020 non-null int64
dst_host_srv_count             494020 non-null int64
dst_host_same_srv_rate         494020 non-null float64
dst_host_diff_srv_rate         494020 non-null float64
dst_host_same_src_port_rate    494020 non-null float64
dst_host_srv_diff_host_rate    494020 non-null float64
dst_host_serror_rate           494020 non-null float64
dst_host_srv_serror_rate       494020 non-null float64
dst_host_rerror_rate           494020 non-null float64
dst_host_srv_rerror_rate       494020 non-null float64
class                          494020 non-null object
dtypes: float64(15), int64(23), object(4)
memory usage: 158.3+ MB
```

There are 4 object types that need to convert to float contains :

```
1. protocol type : 'tcp' , 'udp' , 'icmp'
2. service : 'http' , 'auth' , 'http_443' , etc
3. src_bytes : 'OTH' 'REJ' , 'SF' , etc
4. class : 'normal' , 'neptune' , 'smurf' , etc

model('protocol_type').astype(float)
```

But i got this error :

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

I hope that someone can help me to fix this problem.
Thank you :)

Comment: hi, i think you're meant to do `model['protocol_type'].astype(float)` notice the square brackets `[]` instead of `()`

Comment: thank you for answering my question, i have tried your idea, but i got this error :                                    ValueError: could not convert string to float: tcp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as @thecruisy pointed out, you should use brackets instead of (), which leads to:

```
model['protocol_type'].astype(float)
```

However, since the column is in object (or `str`), that will raise a `ValueError`.

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'tcp'
```

What you should do instead is to *encode* them. You can use either `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
model['protocol_type'].astype('category').cat.codes.astype(float)
#                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#                                   This may be redundant, though
```

Or use `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder`

Comment: Thank you for helping me, but i don't get about 'this may be redundant'. Can you explain to me what is the meaning of that sentences?.

Comment: @DavidReynaldo because without it, the column's `dtype` is already `int`. Not sure what your next move is, but unless it involves strict `type` checking procedure, `int` should do fine.

Comment: thank you, it works. But when i see the info the type is still 'object' like this protocol_type                  494020 non-null object. Can you help me again, please. Thank you

Comment: Have you assigned it back to original df? The operation is not inplace

Comment: @DavidReynaldo after doing `model['protocol_type'] = model['protocol_type'].astype('category').cat.codes`, I get `dtype('int8')` when I do `model['protocol_type'].dtype`. Can you try the same?